# Can OR statements be concatenated in Swift?

Tags: swift

In Swift, is it possible to turn

```
if (a == b) || (a == c) || (a == d) {}
```

into something like the following?

```
if a == (b || c || d) {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot combine the clauses that way, but this might work for you:

```
if [b, c, d].contains(a) { ... }
```

Comment: `contains()` has now changed to `contains(where:)`. So should it be `if [b,c,d].contains(where: {$0 == a})`?

Comment: @JGuo: That is not correct. There are two different `contains()` methods.

Comment: @JGuo, if the (inferred) type of the involved objects conforms to `Equatable`, `[b, c, d]` has a `contains(_:)` method.

Comment: I see. I am comparing tuples of custom enum type, i.e. `(Character, Weapon)`. That's probably why. Thanks!